# FTP Client with pause and resume feature

Tags: ftp

I need to implement FTP client with Pause and Resume feature.

This thread mentions how it can be done for HTTP upload [File upload pause and resume in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847018/file-upload-pause-and-resume-in-android).

Can something similar be done for FTP uploads also?
I will assume server also need to support this feature. Correct?
Some pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Depends how long the pause should be/what you mean by "pause". If short (seconds to minutes), just pause writing to/reading from the stream. If long (minutes to hours or even more), you have to implement transfer resume.

Comment: Also, what language do you want to implement this in?

Comment: The language is c++. The pause can be for more than 5 minutes. I assume this will need support on the server side also, right? How can I implement the transfer-resume in this case, some pointer might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

FTP does not have a feature to transfer only part of the file like HTTP does with the `Content-Range`. But if you want to stop the upload you could simply close the data connection and for resume you would first issue a `SIZE` command to detect the uploaded file size and then a `REST` command with the file position where you want to continue with the upload. Since there is no way to inform the server up-front about the final file size you should probably first upload to a file with a temporary name and after the upload is completed use `RNFR` and `RNTO` to rename it to the final file name.
For more information about these FTP command please have a look at the standard, i.e. [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt).

Comment: There _is_ an (expired) draft for an [FTP RANG](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-bryan-ftp-range-08) command, for requests of ranges of files.

Comment: @Castaglia: interesting. But contrary to mine proposal this needs explicit support in the server and I have no idea which server has this command implemented.

Answer (score 0):

To restore previously interrupted transfer:

- Check size of the already uploaded file part. You can use `SIZE` command or (if your FTP server supports it) the `MLST` command.
- Start new upload using `APPE`, instead of `STOR`. Seek the local source file stream to the already uploaded offset.

  For that to work, the FTP server must support `APPE` command (what most servers do).